# I am getting this error while adding product from django admin panel

Tags: python, django

When i try to add product from django built admin panel i get this error message:

```
/home/pihffall/virtualenv/gngmain/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libjpeg-ba7bf5af.so.9.4.0: file too short
```

Can someone tell me how can i solve this issue ?

Here is my product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='UNCATEGORIZED')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(
        Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="None", null=True, blank=True)
    deal = models.ForeignKey(Deals, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    disc_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True,)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    stockout = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    meta_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    meta_desc = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    offer = models.ForeignKey(OfferCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    stock_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Full Traceback

```
ImportError at /Mithu@64848/store/product/add/
/home/pihffall/virtualenv/gngmain/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/../Pillow.libs/libjpeg-ba7bf5af.so.9.4.0: file too short
```

Comment: Did you try to save a product with a larger image or even without one ?

Answer (score 0):

Prety sure you need to install `Pillow` to create image fields on your models, run `pip install Pillow`

Answer (score 0):

You have a damaged .so file, in this case libjpeg-ba7bf5af.so which needs to be repaired/replaced.  If you are using Centos then see this [Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523497).

You can also try to just remove and reinstall Pillow via pip. `pip uninstall Pillow` then `pip install Pillow`.

If you are using a Debian based system such as ubuntu then look to run `sudo apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev` for example to install libjpeg

Be sure to check and [external libraries](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#external-libraries) you may need Pillow to need.